# How to remove text between <a> with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript and jquery to change the text inside of an a tag. I was reading that document.getElementById("yearA").innerHTML = ''; would remove the text but it isn't working. I'm not sure if it's because I am adding text to the a tag then trying to remove it or not. Any help with this would be appreciated. Here is my html

```js
document.getElementById("filter-div").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("yearA").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("yearA").innerHTML += 'Remove Link';
console.log('Link added')

function hideYear() {
  document.getElementById("yearA").innerHTML = '';
  console.log('Link removed')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTag" />
<div id="filter-div" class="filter-div" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <a id="yearA" onclick="hideYear()" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please use the snippet `<>` feature to create a snippet showing the problem you're having.

Comment: What is `$a` can you post the whole code

Comment: don't mix `javascript` with `jquery` either **use** `javascript` or `jquery`

Comment: Your demo is working fine. Please test again.

Comment: I think it isn't working because I'm using jquery and javascript. I had to change my original post so the code snippet would run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are throwing jquery into the mix, but here is a full example with hide and show functions

HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTag" />
<div id="filter-div" class="filter-div" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <a id="yearA" onclick="hideYear(event)"></a>
    <div id="showYear" onclick="showYear(event)" style="visibility: hidden;">
        show year
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
const year = new Date().getYear();
document.getElementById("filter-div").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("yearA").innerHTML += "Remove " + year;

function hideYear(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("showYear").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("yearA").innerHTML = "";
}

function showYear(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    document.getElementById("showYear").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("yearA").innerHTML = "Remove " + year;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Jquery based solution**

you may try:

```
$('#yearA').text("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make use of `innerHTML`. That will change the entire html node. If your requirement is just to clear the text within the element, try making use if `innerText` property. Select the node either via `JavaScript` or `jQuery`, update the `innerText`, that will preserve the `href` of the `anchor` tag.

Try making use of `innerText`.

**JavaScript Implementation**

```js
function removeText() {
    document.getElementById('google').innerText = '';
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="google">Go To Google</a>
<button onclick="removeText()">Remove Text</button>
```

**jQuery Implementation**

```js
function removeText() {
    $('#google').text('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="google">Go To Google</a>
<button onclick="removeText()">Remove Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this? Let me know.

```js
function hideYear() {
  document.getElementById("yearA").innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTag" />
<div id="filter-div" class="filter-div">
  <a id="yearA" onclick="hideYear()">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for jQuery here.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I added it and forgot to remove it cause she was mixing them both, thanks